# 'ag-grid-angular' is not a known element:

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ag-grid

I have been using ag-grid for a couple of months.  Today, I tried to integrate a grid I have successfully built in a previous project in this Angular template:
[ngx-admin](https://akveo.github.io/ngx-admin/docs/getting-started/installation-guidelines#install-ngxadmin)
This is how the template looks like:
[image]

I tried to add another page inside extra-components which would contain the grid:
[image]
But, as you see the template doesn't get rendered.
This is the extra-components folder inside the project:
[image]

> action-plan.component.html

```
<!-- I have tested this with a normal  Angular project and it worked perfectly -->
ahmed
<ag-grid-angular
style="width: 100% ; height: 1000px;"
[rowData]="actionPlanPartiesrowData"
[columnDefs]="actionPlanPartiescolumnDefs"
(gridReady)="actionPlanPartiesonGridReady($event)"
[getRowHeight]="getRowHeight"
[animateRows]="true"
[defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
(cellValueChanged)="onactionPlanPartiesCellValueChanged($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

> action-plan.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-action-plan",
  templateUrl: "./action-plan.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./action-plan.component.css"]
})
export class ActionPlanComponent implements OnInit {
  private actionPlangridApi;
  actionPlanPartiescolumnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "Id",
      field: "id",
      editable: true,
      width: 100
    },
    {
      headerName: "Project",
      field: "project",
      editable: true,
      width: 400
    },
    {
      headerName: "Risk ID",
      field: "riskId",
      editable: true,
      width: 300
    },
    {
      headerName: "ISO 27001",
      field: "iso27001",
      editable: true,
      width: 150
    },
    {
      headerName: "Priority",
      field: "priority",
      editable: true,
      width: 150
    },
    {
      headerName: "Project Owner",
      field: "projectOwner",
      editable: true,
      width: 150
    },
    {
      headerName: "Estimated Cost",
      field: "estimatedCost",
      editable: true,
      width: 150
    }
  ];
  actionPlanPartiesrowData = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}];
  defaultColDef = {
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    filter: true
  };
  ngOnInit() {}
  constructor() {}
  actionPlanPartiesonGridReady(params) {
  }
  onactionPlanPartiesCellValueChanged(params) {
  }

  public getRowHeight(params) {
    return 130;
  }
}
```

> extra-components.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { TreeModule } from 'angular-tree-component';
import { ToasterModule } from 'angular2-toaster';

import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { ExtraComponentsRoutingModule } from './extra-components-routing.module';

// components
import { ExtraComponentsComponent } from './extra-components.component';
import { TreeComponent } from './tree/tree.component';
import { SpinnerInTabsComponent } from './spinner/spinner-in-tabs/spinner-in-tabs.component';
import { SpinnerInButtonsComponent } from './spinner/spinner-in-buttons/spinner-in-buttons.component';
import { SpinnerSizesComponent } from './spinner/spinner-sizes/spinner-sizes.component';
import { SpinnerColorComponent } from './spinner/spinner-color/spinner-color.component';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './spinner/spinner.component';
import {
  InteractiveProgressBarComponent,
} from './progress-bar/interactive-progress-bar/interactive-progress-bar.component';
import { ProgressBarComponent } from './progress-bar/progress-bar.component';
import { AlertComponent } from './alert/alert.component';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat/chat.component';
import { Tab1Component, Tab2Component, TabsComponent } from './tabs/tabs.component';
import { CalendarComponent } from './calendar/calendar.component';
import { DayCellComponent } from './calendar/day-cell/day-cell.component';
import { StepperComponent } from './stepper/stepper.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { InfiniteListComponent } from './infinite-list/infinite-list.component';
import { NewsPostComponent } from './infinite-list/news-post/news-post.component';
import { NewsPostPlaceholderComponent } from './infinite-list/news-post-placeholder/news-post-placeholder.component';
import { AccordionComponent } from './accordion/accordion.component';
import { NebularFormInputsComponent } from './form-inputs/nebular-form-inputs.component';
import { NebularSelectComponent } from './form-inputs/nebular-select/nebular-select.component';
import { CalendarKitFullCalendarShowcaseComponent } from './calendar-kit/calendar-kit.component';
import { CalendarKitMonthCellComponent } from './calendar-kit/month-cell/month-cell.component';

// service
import { NewsService } from './services/news.service';

import { ActionPlanComponent } from './ahmed/action-plan.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';

const COMPONENTS = [
  ExtraComponentsComponent,
  TreeComponent,
  AlertComponent,
  ProgressBarComponent,
  InteractiveProgressBarComponent,
  SpinnerComponent,
  SpinnerColorComponent,
  SpinnerSizesComponent,
  SpinnerInButtonsComponent,
  SpinnerInTabsComponent,
  CalendarComponent,
  DayCellComponent,
  ChatComponent,
  TabsComponent,
  Tab1Component,
  Tab2Component,
  StepperComponent,
  ListComponent,
  InfiniteListComponent,
  NewsPostComponent,
  NewsPostPlaceholderComponent,
  AccordionComponent,
  NebularFormInputsComponent,
  NebularSelectComponent,
  CalendarKitFullCalendarShowcaseComponent,
  CalendarKitMonthCellComponent,
  ActionPlanComponent
];

const SERVICES = [
  NewsService,
];

const MODULES = [


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ThemeModule,
    ExtraComponentsRoutingModule,
    TreeModule,
    ToasterModule.forRoot(),
    AgGridModule.withComponents([

    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...COMPONENTS,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...SERVICES,
  ],
})
export class ExtraComponentsModule { }
```

Others have faced the same issue as me, but the solution provided is by importing ag-grid-angular to app.module.ts which I did. But, it didn't solve the problem.  (in my case extra-components.module.ts) 
There are other module.ts files in the project in higher level folders in which I also imported the ag-grid-angular module just in case:
[image] 
Here's what appears in VSCode:

> 'ag-grid-angular' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.Angular Can't bind to 'getRowHeight' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
>   1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component and it has 'getRowHeight' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.Angular

Comment: did you run npm install from the console and make sure it succeeded without error?

Comment: @DanGorman I did that as soon as I downloaded the template. For ag-grid I installed it using npm install --save ag-grid-angular and it was succesfully installed I believe . Let me recheck

Comment: @DanGorman Even though I have run npm install --save ag-grid-angular ag-grid-community the two modules aren't found inside node_modules, any idea why?

Comment: Is the package listed as a dependency in the package.json file?

Comment: I have copied pasted the ag-grid-angular module from a previous project. Now ,I am getting this error:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/angularFrameworkOverrides.js.__extends (angularFrameworkOverrides.js:7)
    at angularFrameworkOverrides.js:16
    at Object../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/angularFrameworkOverrides.js

Comment: Is that a wrong way to add a module?

Comment: I understand how you got to this point. What you are doing is normal for someone learning, but prone to error.

There should be a file called package.json it should list all of the packages that your project needs to run. It should have added the package to the list when you ran the npm install earlier. can you add the contents of that file to your post?

Comment: I have checked package.json  and I have this:     "ag-grid-angular": "^20.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",. I have rerun npm install. Now when I run the app I have this error in the console:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/angularFrameworkOverrides.js.__extends (angularFrameworkOverrides.js:7)
    at angularFrameworkOverrides.js:16
    at Object../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/angularFrameworkOverrides.js (angularFrameworkOverrides.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object../node_modules/ag-grid-angular/dist/agGridAngular.js (agGridAngular.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)

Comment: I have solved all the issues. But, the ag-grid doesn't get rendered correctly. I will post it in another question since it's a different issue. Thank you for your time and patience :))

Answer (score 3):

That is a small fix. If you have already followed the procedure at https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/#add-ag-grid-to-your-project, importing **BrowserAnimationsModule** and **FormsModule** will solve the issue.

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Voting up because this worked in my scenario. I upgraded Angular 9 app to Angular 11, and was just copying modules into new Angular 11 app. Turned out I missed BrowserAnimationsModule in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was regarding types array which is there in tsconfig.json.

I was doing unit testing with the help of jest for which had put in type as jest.

When I added node in that array it started accepting ag-grid-angular element.

Before Fix tsconfig.json file :-

```
"types": ["jest"]
```

After fix :-

```
"types": ["node","jest"]
```